# Minimizing a strictly convex quadratic function subject to a single nonconvex quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

For $A\succ 0, B\succeq 0, \rho,\phi>0$, and a given $y$, I am trying the find a cheap yet numerically stable method for solving a sequence of the following problem (it is a penalty method and $\rho$ gradually goes to infinity):

\begin{equation} 
\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}  x^TBx+\rho\|x-y\|^2  \qquad \text{ subject to } \qquad x^TAx\ge \phi.
\end{equation}

The SDP relaxation of this problem is exact and the solution of the relaxation leads to a solution of the original problem above (even if it is not ranked one). But the SDP relaxation is not stable in my numerical experiments (I am using CVXPY and when $\rho$ becomes large, it gives me $-\infty$ as the optimal value, even though clearly my problem is bounded below.)! So, I have to replace it with another effective method. The ideal case is that the method is cheap (so perhaps avoids decomposing the Hessian of the objective function) and stable such that it can be applied to large-scale problems as well.

Comment: You can perhaps introduce a slack variable to convert the inequality constraint into equality: $x^TAx - z^Tz = \phi$. Then you can for example solve efficiently using e.g. bisection on the Lagrange multiplier. For more details see "A constrained eigenvalue problem" by Gander, Golub and von Matt.

Comment: What if you checked whether the minimiser of the quadratic objective is inside or outside the ellipsoid?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. In the simplest case of the problem, where $B$ is zero and $A$ is diagonal, I was receiving errors from the bisection method because the Lagrangian multiplier was in $(-1/d_1,0)$ where $d_1$ is the leading eigenvalue of the $A$. This was often a very small interval and $1+d_1\lambda$ appears in the denominator of the function we need to find its root.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what do you suggest when it is inside though?

Comment: @Sam In that case, intuitively, you would have the constraint $x^T A x = \phi$ instead and use a Lagrange multiplier.  However, relying on intuition is dangerous

Comment: @Sam In this case your problem is just poorly conditioned... It is not the method that is at fault.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cheap"? Also, as you move $\rho$ up, do $A$ and $B$ stay fixed?

Comment: @fedja Computationally cheap is what I mean but I believe staying numerically stable is more important here. 
Yes, $A$ and $B$ stay fixed.

Comment: @Sam What's the size of $A, B$?

Comment: @RiverLi $n$ is at most 100 in my considered application.

Comment: @Sam I tested some randomly generated matrices. If $n = 100$ and $B$ is not full rank, it does not work well (often $X$ is not rank one). If $n=100$ and $B$ is full rank, it works well (often $X$ is rank one).

Comment: @RiverLi My issue is not the solution being rank-one or not! My issue is I keep solving such problems and $\rho$ goes to infinity, say $1.000.000$, then the SDP gives $-\infty$ as the objective function. This is coming from a penalty decomposition method!

Comment: @Sam I have told you it **works well** for large $\rho$ such as $\rho = 10^6$. It is not an issue for me. But non-rank-one $X$ is an issue for me.

Comment: @RiverLi Look at Lemma 2.2 in \link{https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S105262340139001X?casa_token=lPn3X0MlvqgAAAAA:c7H4aFtGA_kcJ2_OuqbW8hp1cvlJRkTYLx0mOdPU2OwU906NyvvVUxLWjdenixCGRt6i1BAxuA}. One can use this decomposition to produce a rank-one solution. By the way, I personally do not trust the numerical results of random matrices.

Comment: @Sam I knew this paper. I want to know if your $B$ is full rank. Are your $A, B$ special? Why your CVX gives $-\infty$? I used matlab+CVX.

Comment: @RiverLi I am not sure that $B$ is for sure full-rank but I think most probably it is. $A$ and $B$ are covariance matrices for 30 assets (from S\&P 500) over two years.